# Converting integer into array of digits

Tags: c++, c

I need to convert two integers into two arrays of digits, so for example 544 would become `arr[0] = 5, arr[1] = 4, arr[2] = 4`.

I have found some algorithms doing this, but they create new array, and return this. I would have to allocate this memory for two arrays, so I wanna pass two integers by reference and do this on them directly.

I guess I can do this, because these integers are in fact template types, so they should be changeable. That's why I added C++ tag here.

Comment: Which are you using, C or C++?

Comment: " into two arrays of digits, so for example" -- There is only one array in your example. And did you have a question?

Comment: You need to learn about modulo division ("remainder") with `%`.  You'd have had it coded faster than it took you to ask the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just using something like this:

```
int n = 544; // your number (this value will Change so you might want a copy)
int i = 0; // the array index
char a[256]; // the array

while (n) { // loop till there's nothing left
    a[i++] = n % 10; // assign the last digit
    n /= 10; // "right shift" the number
}
```

Note that this will result in returning the numbers in reverse order. This can easily be changed by modifying the initial value of `i` as well as the increment/decrement based on how you'd like to determine to length of the value.

---

(Brett Hale) I hope the poster doesn't mind, but I thought I'd add a code snippet I use for this case, since it's not easy to correctly determine the number of decimal digits prior to conversion:

```
{
    char *df = a, *dr = a + i - 1;
    int j = i >> 1;

    while (j--)
    {
        char di = *df, dj = *dr;
        *df++ = dj, *dr-- = di; /* (exchange) */
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want actual characters, than `a[i++] = n % 10` should be changed to `a[i++] = '0' + (n % 10)`

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution is:

```
int i = 12312278;

std::vector<int> digits;

while (i)
{
    digits.push_back(i % 10);

    i /= 10;
}

std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());
```

or, string based ( i >= 0 )

```
for (auto x : to_string(i))
    digits.push_back(x-'0');
```

Comment: Neat idea. Although this won't work for `c`. Not sure why the question is tagged for `c` as well as `c++`.

Answer (score 1):

Call the integer `a`.

To get the units digit of `a`, `a % 10`

To shift `a` down so the tens is the units digit, `a / 10`

To know when you're done, `a == 0`

To know how large your array needs to be in the first place, `min(ceil(log(a+1, 10)), 1)` (to convince yourself this works, try the logarithm part of it in a calculator. if you don't have multiple argument log, use the identity `log(x,y) == log(x)/log(y)`)

Comment: Often it's simpler to just repeatedly divide by 10 to pre-determine out the length of the result.  Probably not much less efficient than using log, and easier to understand/validate.

Comment: @Hot Licks Or you could just use `vector<int>` for everything and never again have to fret about if your array is the right length or not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you are using C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int a=544;
    stringstream str;
    str << a;
    string arr;
    str>>arr;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```