# Converting an integer into an array of digits [C]

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a beginner at programming and I've never posted on here before. I've had a search for answers to my question and one such thread was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987666/converting-integer-into-array-of-digits) ...but I can't get their method to work.

I'm trying to learn C by doing some of the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) challenges. For one of the challenges I need to check if a number is palindromic. I thought I'd do this by loading my target integer, called product, into an array before checking pairs of elements against each other (looking for symmetry).

First I check to see how long my product is:

```
productLength = ceil(log10(product));
```

Then I have a loop to try and load that integer into my array called inspection:

```
for(x = productLength; x <= 0; x--) //decrement from product length and loop
{
    inspection[x - 1] = product % 10; //transfer product values to inspection array
    product /= 10; //prepare product value for next pass (move digits one place to the right)
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm aware it's probably some silly mistake but I can't spot it.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c

Comment: You already got answers, but generally you should explain your problem better, not just *"this doesn't seem to work"*. What result do you expect and what do you actually get? - Also single-stepping in the **debugger** would probably reveal the mistake quickly.

Comment: Did you take into consideration debugging this you own using a real debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
for(x = productLength; x <= 0; x--)
```

should be:

```
for(x = productLength; x >= 0; x--)
```

However, here you have another problem.

```
    inspection[x - 1] = product % 10; //transfer product values to inspection array
```

The loop will reach x = 0 inclusive, so when x = 0, this will cause an invalid index.

So the loop should look like this:

```
for(x = productLength-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    inspection[x] = product % 10;
    product /= 10;
}
inspection[productLength] = 0;
```

Comment: `for( ...; x >= 0; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be:

```
for(x = productLength; x >= 0; x--)
```

instead of `for(x = productLength; x <= 0; x--)`

Comment: The loop shall start with `productLength - 1`.

Comment: That is probably more standard, but he is setting:

    inspection[x - 1]

Comment: Then it shall also be `x > 0`, otherwise you get UB for `x = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

So this line

```
productLength = ceil(log10(product));
```

should easier be

```
productLength = log10(product) + 1;
```

As

```
unsigned x = <some value > 0>;
size_t s = log10(x);
```

is

```
0 for all values of x < 10     
1 for all values of x < 100
2 for all values of x < 1000
...
```

Using `ceil()` works, but I feel using it is overkill.

---

The solution:

```
size_t productLength = log10(product) + 1; 
unsigned char inspection[productLength];

for (size_t x = productLength - 1; x >= 0; --x) //decrement from product length and loop
{
    inspection[x] = product % 10; //transfer product values to inspection array
    product /= 10; //prepare product value for next pass (move digits one place to the right)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an integer you need to palindrome check, then you can just print it in a string and start comparing the characters from both ends:

```
int palindromic(int n)
{
    char str[20];
    int  result;
    int  i;

    sprintf(str, "%d", n);
    int length = strlen(str);

    for (result = 1, i = 0; i < length / 2 && result == 1; i++)
    {
        result = (str[i] == str[length - 1 - i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```