# Convert vector<int> to integer

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I was looking for pre-defined function for converting a vector of integers into a normal integer but i din't find one.

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
```

Need this:

```
int i=123 //directly converted from vector to int
```

Is there a possible way to achieve this?

Comment: what i want is if my vector v contains say elements as 123456 then, if i take integer i, its value must be 123456 directly (by some function from library/ any other way).  I don't want to use pow() to get extract each element of vector and assign it to integer i

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If elements of vector are digits:

```
int result = 0;
for (auto d : v)  
{
    result = result * 10 + d;
}
```

If not digits:

```
stringstream str;
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(str, ""));
int res = stoi(str.str());
```

Comment: A similar solution would be `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto& d){result = result * 10 + d;});`.

Answer (score 9):

Using C++ 11:

```
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
int decimal = 1;
int total = 0;
for (auto& it : v)
{
    total += it * decimal;
    decimal *= 10;
}
```

EDIT: Now it should be the right way.

EDIT 2: See DAle's answer for a shorter/simpler one.

For the sake of wrapping it into a function to make it re-usable. Thanks @Samer

```
int VectorToInt(vector<int> v)
{
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    int decimal = 1;
    int total = 0;
    for (auto& it : v)
    {
        total += it * decimal;
        decimal *= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: for sake of completion why dont you wrap it into a function.

Comment: Reversing is not necessary.  See the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

One liner with C++11 using [std::accumulate()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
auto rz = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0, []( int l, int r ) {
    return l * 10 + r; 
} );
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/LVyJMq)

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with the answer provided by `deepmax` in this post [Converting integer into array of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987666/converting-integer-into-array-of-digits) and the answers provided by multiple users in this post, here is a complete test program with a function to convert an integer to a vector and a function to convert a vector to an integer:

```
// VecToIntToVec.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// function prototypes
int vecToInt(const std::vector<int> &vec);
std::vector<int> intToVec(int num);

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<int> vec = { 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 6 };

  int num = vecToInt(vec);

  std::cout << "num = " << num << "\n\n";

  vec = intToVec(num);

  for (auto &element : vec)
  {
    std::cout << element << ", ";
  }

  return(0);
}

int vecToInt(std::vector<int> vec)
{
  std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    result += (pow(10, i) * vec[i]);
  }

  return(result);
}

std::vector<int> intToVec(int num)
{
  std::vector<int> vec;

  if (num <= 0) return vec;

  while (num > 0)
  {
    vec.push_back(num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
  }

  std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  return(vec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for **negative numbers** too!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

int vectorToInt(vector<int> v) {
  int result = 0;
  if(!v.size()) return result;
  result = result * 10 + v[0];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    result = result * 10 + (v[i] * sgn(v[0]));
  }
  return result;
}

int main(void) {
  vector<int> negative_value = {-1, 9, 9};
  cout << vectorToInt(negative_value) << endl;

  vector<int> zero = {0};
  cout << vectorToInt(zero) << endl;

  vector<int> positive_value = {1, 4, 5, 3};
  cout << vectorToInt(positive_value) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-199
0
1453
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8YTnQuIY9FVJeNKB)</kbd>

The other answers (as of May '19) seem to assume *positive* integers only (maybe 0 too). I had negative inputs, thus, I extended their code to take into account the [sign of the number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c) as well.