# C: How can I separate the characters of a number by taking each number singularly?

Tags: c

how can I separate the characters of a number by taking each number singularly? I have the number 842 and i need to separate it into 8, 4, 2.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987666/converting-integer-into-array-of-digits

Answer (score 0):

- Take the input as a string
- Iterate over it character by character until the end of the string (the null terminator).
- Convert each digit from ASCII to integer by subtracting the value `'0'` from it.